# ts Duplicate identifier 'MercatorProjection'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm totally new to typescript and Angular. I'm having two functions like this.

```
MercatorProjection() {
      this.pixelOrigin_ = new google.maps.Point(TILE_SIZE / 2,
      TILE_SIZE / 2);
      this.pixelsPerLonDegree_ = TILE_SIZE / 360;
      this.pixelsPerLonRadian_ = TILE_SIZE / (2 * Math.PI);
  }

  MercatorProjection.prototype.fromLatLngToPoint = function (latLng,
  opt_point) {
     //code here
  };
```

I'm getting Duplicate identifier 'MercatorProjection' in MercantorProjection.prototype. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: why are you accessing the `prototype`? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In TS, you should use classes, unless there are good reasons why you shouldn't.

Comment: I want to convert this http://jsbin.com/rorecuce/1/edit?html,output  into TS, because I'm using Angular for the project

Comment: @estus ,  messerbill. please help

Comment: I don't see why you would get `Duplicate identifier 'MercatorProjection' in MercantorProjection.prototype` here.

Answer (score 0):

Due to you are using `typescript` you should **not** access `prototype`s unless there is no real reason to do so. You try to convert http://jsbin.com/rorecuce/1/edit?html,output to typescript, so you should do something like this:

```
class MercatorProjection {
    public fromLatLngToPoint(param1, param2) {
      // the code 
    }
    public fromPointToLatLng(param) {
      // the code 
    }
}
```

This typescript class will have the two needed methods that you've tried to append to the `prototype`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: Do I need to add all  //Mercator --BEGIN-- to END (It's in my link) inside this class?

Comment: @venura you need to add everything you want to access